# I want to supply some pdf documents with my application

Tags: java, android

After certain research and lookup over the internet I found that I cannot place these files in the assets folders as those files will be private to my application, I want the native pdf application to be invoked on a button press which redirects the user to the particular document. What I am confused about is how do I bundle the files with my application so that when the user downloads or installs my application these files get stored in her SD-Card.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[copy your assests files to the sdcard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4447477/android-how-to-copy-files-in-assets-to-sdcard) and when clicking on the button open the files in the sdcard as like this

```
 File rootDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

 File file = new File(rootDir + "/filepath/"+fileName);//give the file path here
 if(file.exists())
   {
    // do action here
   }
```

Comment: I dont have the files in the assets folder now as I came to know they are not public, to place them on the SD-Card do I have to use the above method? Or there is a better way for this?

Comment: coping files from app to sd card is better. the above method works fine for your requirement.